# About Convolution Theorem

Tags: numpy, fourier-transform, convolution

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as ss
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([4, 5, 6])
np.convolve(x,y) --> gave me result as array([ 4, 13, 28, 27, 18])
```

Now, I wanted to get the same answer using FFT and the code is below.

```
a = fft(x)
b = fft(y)
d = ifft(x*y)
d --> gives array([31.+0.j, 31.+0.j, 28.-0.j])
```

Would appreciate if anyone could provide the right code or let me know why it is so?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Specifically, have you thought about why it is that the first snippet gives you an array of length 5 and the second of length 3?